# How to create many directories with access control by using powershell 2.0

Tags: powershell

I am trying to learn the win2008 r2

In the win2008 r2, i create many student users . So i need to create the independent directory   for storage file (Read ,write,execute).

In dc C:\place\
i create many directories and set the ntfs quota in 1GB. So they see the N: in their account when they login the client server.

StudID = folder name
Such as :
S00001
S00002
S00003
S00005
......
......

How can i set the access control to avoid the student to visit another directories?

Now, i haven't setup the permission. The student can visit the other folder of student by using the path.